Is there any way to decode NALu in browser?
Environment
I am developing a product for a highly restricted environment (e.g., military, casinos) where installing my media server(for transcoding) is not allowed. As a result, I need to handle video decoding entirely in the browser. Specifically, Their system sends me(CEF embedded browser) H264 or H265 NAL units, and I need to decode them into YUV frames within a browser environment.
WebRTC cannot be used. Internet or External Network or something server that placed on outside of their network cannot be used.
Main Question
Here are my main questions:

Are there any alternative methods or APIs to decode H264/H265 NAL units into YUV frames in the browser
Are there any reliable and licensed JavaScript libraries or WebAssembly-based solutions for H264/H265 decoding that can be used in a commercial product?

Thankyou
Already Tried
I have already tried using the WebCodecs API for decoding, but due to compatibility issues(CEF embedded chromium is not available for WebCodecs API), it is not a valid solution for this project.
Additionally, I have looked into WebAssembly-based decoders like Broadway.js (for H264) and H265Player and I already implemented a player using these decoders and deployed some projects. However, I have concerns about the legitimacy of their licensing claims. It seems that the original source code for their WebAssembly implementation is not applied to their projects' license.

Given this restricted environment, I'm shocked that there is worry about media components and not the whole monolith of Chromium.  Anyway... probably the way forward is for you to build Chromium with the codecs you need, and continue on with the Web Codecs API.  For licensing in a domain like this, you should probably find a lawyer with experience on licensing from MPEG LA.  It's likely that you won't have to pay anything, given the limited distribution scope and that you're just decoding, but you should really find out for sure.  (continued...)

Also be aware of licensing terms around exports, military usage, etc.  You're bumping up into a lot of red flags that you'll need legal advice to properly answer.  Finally, don't forget to meet your obligations under all the open source licenses!

@GyeongHoKim Browsers work with pixels in RGBA mode. If you decode a video frame (or NALU) in html5 then you must also be willing to write a RGB to YUV converter (and be grateful if not needed). Why does it need to be YUV instead of RGB/A? What exactly are you doing with the YUV data? (Pass it to another software? Just display in browser?)

@VC.One I convert YUV frame to RGB to display in browser. Because most decoders that I found decode NALu to YUV frame. If there is any way to take RGB frame directly from NALu or RTP Packet, please tell me.

@Brad Your first sentence makes me think "So what has Chromium done to you lately, huh?". PS: The restrictions might be more like they want to minimize the number of external dependencies (military and casinos would be paranoid about what "leveraged" third-party code really does). Notice "...Where installing my media server (for transcoding) is not allowed". I guess no military base wants some GET requests happening to a server they don't control. This is solvable through muxing with Javascript.

@GyeongHoKim What is the licensing claims (link) that you need advice about? The solution is to mux NALUs into MP4 fragments as already said by MarkusSchumann. That avoids needing a server to transcode. I see in docs that Broadway.JS only supports Baseline profile of H264. Did you test playback for any videos encoded at Main or High profile? I was going to suggest how to mux manually but I don't know if you've got experience of working with bytes? PS: If these tools work nicely then what is the problem?

@VC.One Heh, don't get me wrong, I love Chromium, I just don't understand the specific security risk of a media server that probably just shells out to FFmpeg or something, vs. alllll of that same stuff embedded, plus thousands of others, into a build of Chromium.  If it really is so restricted that some server cannot be deployed internally.  My understanding of the "server" was that it would just be a component installed inside the wall.  To me, there really isn't a difference between what's needed, and the distinction between server/client is a bit arbitrary here, in terms of security needs.

I would wrap your NAL unit stream into fragmented MP4 chunks and then hand it to the video tag.
For example - start looking here: https://github.com/Vanilagy/mp4-muxer
This will cause latency measured in seconds but you can keep the fragment size small.

Thank you for your answer, that's awsome. However I already know how to mux. Unfortunately, this project should guarantee Real-time.

Sounds good.
To the best of my knowledge - real-time means that you have a guarantied response time. But the absolute duration can be anything two parties agree on.
Consider adding your latency requirement to your question.
What's the max allowable glass to glass latency?
How much latency do you have before decoding starts?

@GyeongHoKim "I already know how to mux." how are you doing the muxing exactly? Is it slow because of waiting for some other library's multiple functions to generate an MP4 chunk? Or  maybe you understand MP4 bytes editing? If you know MP4 bytes then to paste NALU data inside some already prepared MP4 header bytes is faster than waiting for someone else's code (like Broadway/MP4-Muxer/etc with multiple functions) to generate such MP4 header bytes (encode) per frame or chunk.
